# Unknown database file format .DAT

Tags: database-design

I am trying to find out the database name of this file.

I opened it via hex editor:

http://gyazo.com/5b579bd2ef9620aa833bf0743a480230

Any help is appreciated.

Client sent me this file. It is very old of his DOS program but not sure which database it is.

Any help is appreciated.

When I open it using Notepad I see this:

```
 €D                                                                      D                         147306154      340000          ‡      P„                                    Ã                     124126290      340001        O‰      †                                    Ä                     124126323      340002       ÀDŠ      ‡                                    Å                     124126289      340003        BŠ      ‡                                    Æ                     124126202      340004
     @Š      ‡                                    Ç                     124126253      340005
     €{Š      `‡                                    È                     124126244      340006       $‹      h‡                                    É                     124126245      340007
```

Comment: Try it with  **"Clarion Viewer"**.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of a flat file database. There was a Swedish producer that was creating them, but I cannot remember their name right now.

Something like https://filedb.codeplex.com/

(I meant this as a comment, not as an answer, but I do not have enough rights to comment these days.)

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way of telling with the information you have.

Back in those days a lot of applications used a proprietary database format only readable by the application itself.

Sometimes the first bytes are a header which may tell you what it is.

I think your best bet would be to run it through [file](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) and hope that tool detects it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a DataFlex data table.

If the client has a dfrun.exe on the PC, then you can be 99% sure.

If you're lucky, it also has a dfquery.exe, which will let you export the table as a .csv file.